# Rails Skip Validation For Nested Attribute if condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I skip validation for nested_attribute if condition is true

aquarium.rb

```
 has_many :fishes
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :fishes,
```

fish.rb

```
belongs_to :aquarium 
validates :ratio, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, if: :skip_this_validation
```

then in aquariums_controller.rb

```
def some_action
    @aquarium = Aquarium.new(aqua_params)
    @aquarium.skip_this_validation = true  # i know that this is not valid
    #must skip validation for ratio and then save to DB
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**aquarium.rb**

```
has_many :fishes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fishes,
attr_accessor :skip_fishes_ratio_validation
```

**fish.rb**

```
belongs_to :aquarium 
validates :ratio, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, unless: proc { |f| f.aquarium&.skip_fishes_ratio_validation }
```

then in **aquariums_controller.rb**

```
def some_action
  @aquarium = Aquarium.new(aqua_params)
  @aquarium.skip_fishes_ratio_validation = true
  @aquarium.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you Max for this. I've been searching for hours on the net, this is what I definitely need

Comment: Hi @romiesilvano ! You're welcome ! I'm glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the condition in method and check for the [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)

```
class Fish < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :ratio, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, if: :custom_validation

  private

  def custom_validation
    # some_condition_here
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@aquarium.save(validate: false)
```

I believe skips validations on the model.

Comment: But I need to run validation for some field, I just want to skip validation on specific field.

Comment: In which case, the easiest way would be a custom validation with a method that contains the condition to skip. I think Deepak has just posted what you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 you can simply pass `optional: true` to the `belongs_to` association.

So in your `fish.rb`, update association with the following code:

```
belongs_to :aquarium, optional: true
```

It will skip association validation if the `fish` object has no `aquarium`.